# Maximo Spatial: Access the list of features in the Results Window via an automation script?

Tags: resultset, maximo

*Maximo 7.6.1.1/Spatial 7.6.0.5*

In the map tab in Maximo Spatial, there is a window called the [Results Window](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSG2D3_7.6.0.1/com.ibm.spl.doc/maps/c_result_map_feature_query.html) ([*image source*](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-functionality-behind-merge-tool-maximo-spatial-76x)):

[image]

I want to access the list of features in the Results Window via a Jython automation script/custom Action.

I've searched the Java classes but I can't seem to find the appropriate class/method to do this.

Any ideas?

<sup>*Keyword: Maximo Spatial*</sup>

---

Answer (score 2):

IMO you cannot because ResultWindow is a javascript widget that runs in your browser meanwhile the auto-scripts run on server-side (inside Maximo)

Answer (score 1):

@dvisentin is right, but you can make your own REST call from an autoscript to the GIS service. The Scripting 76 Features document has a library script early on that you can use to get you started. Then you may want to use the JSONObject and JSONArray classes if the GIS service returns data in JSON format.